# Ignited+datatables -> order by

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I'm using codeigniter with datatables and i want to order a select by a column.

How can i do that ?

```
$this->datatables->select('col_1, col_2, col_3');
$this->datatables->from('table');

....$this->datatables->order ?!?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use:

```
$this->db->order_by("column name", "desc");
```

Comment: yes it works. thanks bro. all this time i was searching for a datatables function.

Comment: it do work with datatables, but when you use datatables its own column ordering. it will give error. it will stay on top and rest fields go up and down, which makes the record bad :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the aaSorting parameter to order the table on initialization.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [[2,'asc'], [3,'desc']]
  } );
} );
```

where 2 and 3 are column's index

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way i am controlling here all required value with codeigniter DATA-TABLE and MYSQL select include a small joining

```
function get_ComponentList($rowperpage, $row, $search='',$order, $dir)
{ 
$this->db->select('a.component_id, a.component_name as component_name, a.eco_code as eco_code, b.component_name as parent_name');
    $this->db->from('component_info as a');
    $this->db->join('component_info as b', 'b.component_id = a.parent_id', 'left');
    $this->db->order_by($order,$dir);
            if($search != ''){
            $this->db->like('a.component_name', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('a.eco_code', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('b.component_name', $search);
            }    
            $this->db->limit($rowperpage,$row);
           $query = $query->result(); 
    return $query;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use with $this->datatables, you need to make a custom function for that, add the below custom function in Datatables.php library file:

```
public function corder_by($column, $type = ASC)
{
  $this->order_by[] = array($column, $type);
  $this->ci->db->order_by($column, $type);
  return $this;
}
```

If the sorting type is not defined "ASC/DESC", then it will by default sort as "Ascending".

And use it as:

```
$this->datatables->corder_by('column_name','desc');
```